# How to detect figures in a xy dataset?

Tags: c#, algorithm, dataset, line, point

I'm working with a dataset of XY values. There was a lot of noise, I used a DBSCAN algorithm to reduce it. What I need to do, is tune the data to form a pattern. Here is an example of what I mean.
How can I get a result like the blue line?
[image: pattern]

I used a  DBSCAN algorithm to reduce the noise of the points, combined with a median filter. And also tried with the average

```
   foreach (var item in _cluster.Clusters)
        {
            var points_ordered = item.Objects.OrderBy(x => x.Point.X).ThenByDescending(x => x.Point.Y).ToArray();

            var avg_x_point = points_ordered.Sum(x => x.Point.X) / points_ordered.Length;
            var avg_y_point = points_ordered.Sum(x => x.Point.Y) / points_ordered.Length;


            nlist.Add(new R2000ScanPoint
            {
                X = avg_x_point,
                Y = avg_y_point
            });

        }

        return nlist.ToArray();
```

Comment: But you got what I mean  right?

Comment: I edited the question, adding the code to calculate the avg point of a cluster, but with that I only get  the red points, but as you can see, there is a high level of fluctioation

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  I'm sure someone who knows more about this subject will be along soon to help.  Sorry I can't help more.  Good luck! :)

Comment: linear regression could do the trick